# Can python's slice notation be used outside of brackets?

Tags: python, slice

Within brackets, python's slice shorthand auto-generates tuples of slice objects:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        print key

Foo()[1::, 2:20:5]
```

This prints `(slice(1, None, None), slice(2, 20, 5))`. As far as I can tell, however, this shorthand doesn't work outside brackets.

Is there any way to use slice shorthand in other contexts? I could define a dummy object that simply returns whatever it is passed to `__getitem__` -- that would at least give me a way to generate slice tuples using the shorthand syntax. Is there a more pythonic way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NumPy has an [`s_`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.s_.html) object that will do this for you:

```
>>> np.s_[2::2]
slice(2, None, 2)
```

You can easily make your own version of this simply by setting `s_ = Foo()` and then using `s_` whenever you want to create a slice easily.

Answer (score 2):

What you see printed out is actually a good clue. You can create slice objects directly through the slice() global function. These can then be passed used to index from lists.

```
s = slice(1, 10, 2)
numbers = list(range(20))
print numbers[s]
print numbers[1:10:2]
```

This will print the same result twice, [1, 3, 5, 7, 9].

The slice instances have a few attributes and methods. You can look at help(slice) to see more.

Comment: the OP wants a way to use the bracket shorthand to generate slice objects.